# Entity Framework 4 & Self-Tracking Entities?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I was recently listening to a podcast "herding code" where Julia Lerman was the guest. They were discussing the changes that were made in EF4. They got into the subject of Self-Tracking entities. Julia had said that self tracking entities were not perfect and that they were made for WCF and wouldn't work with asp.net. This is my main question. Of course they didn't any other details than that. Works for WCF and not for ASP.Net huh? What exactly does that mean? So what happens when you send the self-tracking entities to the presentation layer and the presentation layer is asp.net? She also said they weren't very interoperable and that if you presentation layer had .Net Framework 3.5 you could get it to work but it would take a little extra work.

She goes on to say that POCO template is the perfect solution and  you can manage your "change type" notifications with classes designed with this template. Is there some type of mechanism to track these notifications or is it something your expected to handle manually?

So she really made it sound like she really liked the POCO template but the self-tracking entities solution was limited.

Comment: They will work with ASP.NET, but they're totally unnecessary for ASP.NET, since they'll never be disconnected from the server in that context.